# GnuCOBOL PIC 999V99 - unexpected result?

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

What am I doing wrong with the following piece of code under GnuCOBOL 3.1-rc1.0?

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID.     NUMTEST.
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01 NUM         PIC 999V99.
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       DISPLAY "ENTER NUMBER: ". 
       ACCEPT NUM.
       DISPLAY "NUMBER = ".
       DISPLAY NUM.
       STOP RUN.
```

I enter 123.45 as my input. I'm expecting 123.45 as the output, but instead I get 123.40

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are plain `ACCEPT`s, they only read in data from the command line (you can also enter a big lorem ipsum there).

While I think it is a reasonable request to have this working "as expected" the best option you currently have is `ACCEPT`ing only `PIC X` and then use `MOVE FUNCTON NUMVAL (INPUT-DATA) TO NUM` (maybe test the data with `FUNCTION TEST-NUMVAL()` before). For `DISPLAY` you likely want an edited field with a `PICTURE` like `ZZ9.99`.

In any case: be aware that `V` is an *implied* decimal point, it is not part of the actual storage.

Using "extended" screenio (= input not from the command line) gives some benefits (like only allowing numeric data and not more than the fields's size) but has different culprits (for example you should use `COLUMN`/`LINE` for it and numeric `ACCEPT` still has some issues in GC 3.1).

As suggested by JoelFan I've tested edited fields - these work currently *only* correctly when in "command line mode" (so not if any attributes like positioning is used):

```
       PROGRAM-ID.     NUMTEST.
       DATA DIVISION.
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
        01 NUM-INP     PIC 999.99.
        01 NUM         PIC 999V99.
        01 NUM-OUT     PIC zz9.99.
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
           DISPLAY "ENTER NUMBER: ". 
           ACCEPT NUM-INP.
           DISPLAY "NUMBER = ".
           MOVE NUM-INP TO NUM
           MOVE NUM     TO NUM-OUT
           DISPLAY NUM "/" NUM-OUT.
           STOP RUN.
```

Producing the expected result:

```
ENTER NUMBER:
123.45
NUMBER =
123.45/123.45

ENTER NUMBER:
1.2
NUMBER =
001.20/  1.20

ENTER NUMBER:
a
NUMBER =
000.00/  0.00

ENTER NUMBER:
1234567
NUMBER =
567.00/567.00
```

Note: the third case should actually raise an exception when compiled with `-fec=all` / `-debug` (currently doesn't), the last case is completely correct as numbers are right justified.

Still: `ACCEPT`ing alphanumeric data, do explicit checks/conversions, and display as edited field like `NUM-OUT` above is the safest option.

Comment: Thanks for your help Simon. Looks like I need to look into this FUNCTION NUMVAL thing. I've not come across it before (I last touched COBOL around 1988 or 1989, at college!)

Comment: What about changing `INPUT-DATA` to use an edited pic (`999.99` instead of `999V99`)?

Comment: GnuCOBOL may not accepting edited items with decimal-points as "extended" (non-command-line) screen inputs correctly - but if you don't need the "extended" version and have no issues with non-standard use (most of the screen i/o is not standardized) then: yes it does work correctly (as long as you only enter valid data). I''ll update the post.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm PIC 999.99 works perfectly for an input of 123.45. Many thanks Simon and JoelFan